# Acquiring Ground Truth for ISIC 2019 Challenge Test Set for Publication Purposes

Tags: dataset

I have been working with the dataset from the ISIC 2019 challenge, which is not live anymore. I was hoping to find the ground truth data for the test set published on the [official website](https://challenge.isic-archive.com/data/#2019) for further evaluation purposes in a forthcoming publication.

However, I couldn't locate this information. Is there an alternative means to acquire the ground truth for the ISIC 2019 challenge test set? If anyone has experience with or knowledge about this, I would greatly appreciate your input.